# What exactly were the "asymmetries which do not appear to be inherent in the phenomena" in Einstein's 1905 SR paper?

Tags: special-relativity, history

The first ¶ of Einstein's "[On the Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies](https://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/specrel/www/)" says (my emphases):

> It is known that Maxwell's electrodynamics—as usually understood at the present time—when applied to moving bodies, leads to **asymmetries which do not appear to be inherent in the phenomena**. Take, for example, the reciprocal electrodynamic action of a magnet and a conductor. The observable phenomenon here depends only on the relative motion of the conductor and the magnet, whereas the customary view draws a sharp distinction between the two cases in which either the one or the other of these bodies is in motion. For if the magnet is in motion and the conductor at rest, **there arises in the neighbourhood of the magnet an electric field with a certain definite energy**, producing a current at the places where parts of the conductor are situated. But if the magnet is stationary and the conductor in motion, no electric field arises in the neighbourhood of the magnet. In the conductor, however, we find an electromotive force, to which in itself there is no corresponding energy, but which gives rise—assuming equality of relative motion in the two cases discussed—to electric currents of the same path and intensity as those produced by the electric forces in the former case.

What exactly are these "asymmetries which do not appear to be inherent in the phenomena"? Why did Einstein say "there arises *in the neighbourhood* of the magnet…"?

Comment: Your first question is literally answered right after the sentence you reproduced in bold.

Comment: And the second question's answer is simply that he was trying to describe how current is generated in a coil which is situated in the neighbourhood of the magnet. So he talks about what happens in the neighbourhood of the magnet.

Comment: His point is that when you bring a magnet and a coil together, there is no real distinction between moving the magnet toward the coil, or moving the coil toward the magnet, or both at the same time. They seem, to Einstein to be *identical* physical situations. Yet the (pre-relativistic) mathematical formulation of these scenarios are all different - they are different mathematical representations of one and the same phenomena. This is described by Einstein as an asymmetry in the mathematical representations that doesn't seem to have any grounding in the phenomena.

Comment: @Danu Could you please explain how so?

Comment: @PhysicsFootnotes "the (pre-relativistic) mathematical formulation of these scenarios are all different" They are? Could you give an example where in 19th century E&M the "mathematical formulation[s] of these scenarios are all different"?

Comment: How does the question lack details/clarity? It seems very clear: "What are the asymmetries which do not appear to be inherent in the phenomena?"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Einstein, when discussing the "asymmetries which do not appear to be inherent in the phenomena," was referring to a particular interpretation of Lorentz's electrodynamics that he learned, during 1896-1900, from an 1894 book by Föppl.

- See §15.1.6, "Origin of the Asymmetry Pointed Out by Einstein," pp.
  264-265 (PDF pp. 284-285) of [André K. T. Assis](http://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~assis/books.htm)'s free
  [*Relational Mechanics and Implementation of Mach's Principle with
  Weber's Gravitational Force*](http://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~assis/Relational-Mechanics-Mach-Weber.pdf).

  - See Faraday's, Maxwell's, and Weber's explanation of this phenomenen in the passages quoted on [*ibid.*](http://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~assis/Relational-Mechanics-Mach-Weber.pdf) pp. 258-264 (PDF pp. 278-284).

Answer (score 0):

According to Faraday, a moving magnet induces an electric field.  There is a field energy density attributable to the electric field.  For example, we can calculate the work needed to charge a capacitor. Then treating the field between the plates as effectively uniform we divide the calculated energy by the volume between the plates.

When the magnet is viewed as stationary, and the wire is moved, the charges in the wire are subject to the Lorentz force. (I believe this is how Einstein would have understood it.)  But the Lorentz force attributes no electric field to the magnet.  Thus, the total system energy calculation for the stationary magnet with a moving wire, is less than the total energy calculation for the stationary wire with a moving magnet.

As with the electric field, there **is** a magnetic field energy, but that is present in both scenarios.